# Lambda parameter causes recomposition

Tags: android, lambda, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

When passing lambda to button's onClick, it triggers recomposition every time parent is recomposed.

I somewhat understand why that happens, because for lambda is just object of a class and if it contains unstable variables, it will trigger recomposition.

```
fun mainScreenDestination(
    viewModel: MainViewModel.ViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
   HomeScreenHeader(
      title = //some mutable data
      onStatsClick = {
             viewModel.onStatsClicked()
          }
    )
}


@Composable
fun HomeScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    onStatsClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    Button(
          onClick = onStatsClick,
          .....
     ){}

   Text(text = title)
}
```

1. So the solution I find everywhere is to pass reference to the function as a parameter, but result is same for me, why doesn't it work?

```
fun mainScreenDestination(
    viewModel: MainViewModel.ViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
   HomeScreenHeader(
      title = //some mutable data
      onStatsClick = viewModel::onStatsClicked
    )
}
```

2. And the next solution is to remember lambda in composition context and pass it as

```
 val onStatsClicked = remember<() -> Unit> { viewModel::onStatsClicked}
```

even tho this works what are the alternatives, because I dont want to "remember" all the needed lambdas

Comment: Can you be more specific which composable is recomposed when what changes? The code you provided so far works as it should, there are no additional recompositions.

Comment: Did you try enabling [strong skipping mode](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-strong-skipping-mode-explained-cbdb2aa4b900)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I added another Text composable, in this case if value of title is changed Text composable will be recomposed. But also, the Button is recomposing because lambda is not stable, doesn't matter if I pass it by reference or not.

Comment: Still not reproducible, I do not observe recompositions of the Button composable with your code.